# Spring MVC: Set Year field using Joda DateTime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jodatime

**GOAL:**

Set 4-digit Year (e.g. 1999) field to LocalDate Controller attribute. How do I set the input::1999 to DateTime object in Spring MVC?

**JSP:**

```
<form:form action="${url}" method="POST" commandName="form">
    <form:input id="year" path="works[0].startDate.year"/>
</form:form>
```

**SETTER:** DateTime updated with 4-digit year

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class WorkRequest {
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
    @XmlElement(name = "start_date")
    public DateTime startDate;

    public void setStartDate(DateTime startDate){
    //update 4-digit only
    }    
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How to set 1999 to DateTime object in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, if you only want to update the year of a LocalTime then you can do the following:

```
public void setStartDate(DateTime startDate){
    this.startDate = this.startDate.year().setCopy(startDate.year().get());
}
```

But what has Spring got to do with that?